# Why is my Karatsuba multiplier not giving right answers for large numbers?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, hdl, multiplier

I tried to implement 16-Bit Karasutba Multiplier in Verilog HDL. It gives me right answers for small numbers, but it's incorrect for large numbers.

Can someone point out what's wrong?

Here's the design:

```
module karatsuba_2x2(
    input [1:0] a,
    input [1:0] b,
    output [3:0] out
);

    wire temp;

    assign out[0]= a[0] & b[0];

    assign out[1] = (a[1] & b[0]) ^ (a[0] & b[1]);
    assign temp =  (a[1] & b[0]) & (a[0] & b[1]);

    assign out[2] = temp ^(a[1] & b[1]);
    assign out[3] = temp &(a[1] & b[1]);    

endmodule

module karatsuba_4x4(
    input [3:0] a,
    input [3:0] b,
    output [7:0] out
);

    wire [3:0] ac, bc, ad, bd;
    wire [7:0] t1, t2;
    wire [6:0] psum;
    
    karatsuba_2x2 k1(.a(a[3:2]), .b(b[3:2]), .out(ac));
    karatsuba_2x2 k2(.a(a[1:0]), .b(b[3:2]), .out(bc));
    karatsuba_2x2 k3(.a(a[3:2]), .b(b[1:0]), .out(ad));
    karatsuba_2x2 k4(.a(a[1:0]), .b(b[1:0]), .out(bd));

    assign t2 = bd;
    assign psum = {bc+ad, 2'b00};
    assign t1 = {ac, 4'b0000};
    assign out = t1 + t2 + psum;
  
endmodule

module karatsuba_8x8(
    input [7:0] a,
    input [7:0] b,
    output [15:0] out
);
    
    wire [7:0] ac, bc, ad, bd;
    wire [15:0] t1, t2;
    wire [12:0] psum;
    
    karatsuba_4x4 k1(.a(a[7:4]), .b(b[7:4]), .out(ac));
    karatsuba_4x4 k2(.a(a[3:0]), .b(b[7:4]), .out(bc));
    karatsuba_4x4 k3(.a(a[7:4]), .b(b[3:0]), .out(ad));
    karatsuba_4x4 k4(.a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0]), .out(bd));
    
    assign t2 = bd;
    assign psum = {bc+ad, 4'b0000};
    assign t1 = {ac, 8'b0000};
    assign out = t1 + t2 + psum;
endmodule

// Top Module
module karatsuba_16x16(
    input [15:0] a,
    input [15:0] b,
    output [31:0] out
);
    
    wire [15:0] ac, bc, ad, bd;
    wire [31:0] t1, t2;
    wire [24:0] psum;
    
    karatsuba_8x8 k1(.a(a[15:8]), .b(b[15:8]), .out(ac));
    karatsuba_8x8 k2(.a(a[7:0]),. b(b[15:8]),. out(bc));
    karatsuba_8x8 k3(.a(a[15:8]), .b(b[7:0]),. out(ad));
    karatsuba_8x8 k4(.a(a[7:0]),. b(b[7:0]),. out(bd));

    assign t2 = bd;
    assign psum = {bc+ad, 8'b00000000};
    assign t1 = {ac, 16'b0000000000000000};
    assign out = t1 + t2 + psum;
    
endmodule
```

Here's the testbench:

```
module tb;
    reg [15:0] a,b;
    wire [31:0] out;

    karatsuba_16x16 DUT(a,b,out);

    initial begin
        {a,b} = 0;

        $monitor("a = %d | b = %d | out = %d", a,b,out);

        #2 a = 'd3; b = 'd3;
        #2 a = 'd65535; b = 'd3;
        #2 a = 'd65535; b = 'd33333;
        #2 a = 'd65535; b = 'd50000;


        #2 $finish;
    end

endmodule
```

Here's the output:

[image: It calculates (65535 x 33333) correctly but (65535 x 50000) incorrectly]

It calculates (65535 x 33333) correctly but (65535 x 50000) incorrectly.

Comment: @toolic 2x2, 4x4 and 8x8 modules are working fine. I checked them for all possible combinations. The problem lies in the 16x16 module. It's giving a correct answer till (65535 x 33342). From (65535 x 33343) onwards it's giving an incorrect answer less than the correct answer. Eg: (65535 x 3343) gives 2,184,853,889 instead of 2,185,133,505.

Comment: see my answer....

Comment: I think your 2×2 nice. But *none* of this "is Karatsuba". For starters, the whole point is each level using **3 smaller multipliers instead of 4**. (And the tag [multiplier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/multiplier/info) doesn't apply, as it isn't even about "analogue" voltage multipliers.)

Comment: @greybeard Yea, i realised that too. So, i tried implementing the actual Karatsuba multiplier. But there too, i am facing issues. If you can, then pls look into [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674025/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-this-2x2-karatsuba-multiplier-in-verilog-hdl)

Answer (score 8):

That's a lot of code to go through, so you can break the problem down to debug it: thoroughly check the 2x2 module to make sure it works. Then check the 4x4 module, etc. This should narrow your problem down.

I checked 2x2, and it is fine.

There is a problem with 4x4.  With the following small testbench, I get an error when `a` and `b` hit their maximum values (15):

```
module tb;
    reg [15:0] a,b;
    wire [7:0] out4;

    karatsuba_4x4 DUT4(a[3:0], b[3:0], out4);

    initial begin
        for (int i=0;i<16;i++) begin
            for (int j=0;j<16;j++) begin
                #1;
                a=i; b=j;
                #1;
                $display(a,,b," = ",out4);
                if (out4 !== (a*b)) $display("ERROR");
            end
        end
        #2 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

Here is a snippet of the output:

```
   15    12 = 180
   15    13 = 195
   15    14 = 210
   15    15 = 161
ERROR
```

This is fixed by changing:

```
assign psum = {bc+ad, 2'b00};
```

to:

```
assign psum = (bc+ad) << 2;
```

Use the shift-left operator (`<<`) for `psum` in the 8x8 and 16x16 modules as well.

```
assign psum = (bc+ad) << 4;
assign psum = (bc+ad) << 8;
```

With these changes, I get the output you expect:

```
a =     0 | b =     0 | out =          0
a =     3 | b =     3 | out =          9
a = 65535 | b =     3 | out =     196605
a = 65535 | b = 33333 | out = 2184478155
a = 65535 | b = 50000 | out = 3276750000
```

There are subtleties associated with using the concatenation operator (`{}`) regarding signal bit widths.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, Table 11-21— *Bit lengths resulting from self-determined expressions*.  The problem with your code is that items in a concatenation are self-determined.  The item `bc+ad` is self-determined, meaning the length of the expression for the `+` operator is determined by the 2 terms, both of which are 4-bit.  So, the sum is truncated to 4-bit, instead of the desired 5-bit.