# What am I doing wrong with this 2x2 Karatsuba Multiplier in Verilog HDL?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, hdl, multiplier

I am trying to implement a 2x2 karatsuba Multiplier which I will be using as a base case for a higher bit multiplier.

Here's the code:

```
module karatsuba_2x2(
    input [1:0] a,
    input [1:0] b,
    output [3:0] out
);   

    wire t1, t2, t3;

    assign t1 = a[1] & b[1];
    assign t2 = (a[0] ^ a[1]) & (b[0] ^ b[1]);
    assign t3 = a[0] & b[0];

    assign out = (t1<<2) + ((t2 ^ t1 ^ t3)<<1) + t3;

endmodule
```

I am trying to implement this **arithmetical expression** *(not boolean)* -

`out = a*b = 2^2.(a[1]*b[1]) + 2^1.{(a[1]+a[0]).(b[1]+b[0]) - a[1]*b[1] - a[0]*b[0]} + a[0]*b[0]`

On simulating with a testbench, it shows 3x3 = 5, every other combination gives correct answer.
Here's the testbench:

```
module tb;
    reg [1:0] a,b;
    wire [3:0] out;
    integer i,j;

    karatsuba_2x2 DUT(a,b,out);

    initial begin
        $monitor("a = %d | b = %d | out = %d", a,b,out);

        for (i = 0; i<4; i=i+1) begin
            for (j = 0; j<4; j=j+1) begin
                a=i;
                b=j;
                #2;
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Overflow in T2.

Comment: @user_1818839 How should I fix it?

Comment: Handle the overflow.

Comment: @user_1818839 t2 is assigned to an and operation of two xor expressions equating to two single bits. So how is it overflowing?

Comment: What is `(a[1]+a[0]).(b[1]+b[0])` evaluated by hand in the failing case? Or even just `a[1]+a[0]`?

Comment: The notion you used in the equation is inconsistent.  `*` is used for both MULTIPLY and bitwise-AND? `+` is used for both ADD and bitwise-OR?  What is `.` for?  Can you post a link for the equation?

Comment: @toolic The out = a*b = ... equation is arithmetic, not boolean. Hence * and . means MULTIPLY and + means ADD.

Comment: Edit all new information into the question, not here in the comments.

Comment: While your best bet to design a 16×16 bit Karatsuba Multiplier should be to start at the big end (8×8 multipliers won't *quite* get you there…), you don't show how you arrived at `(a[0] ^ a[1]) & (b[0] ^ b[1])` to implement `(a[1]+a[0])*(b[1]+b[0]) - a[1]*b[1] - a[0]*b[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you declared the `t` Verilog signals as 1-bit wide:

```
wire t1, t2, t3;
```

That means that `out` can never be 9.  The `t` signals can only be 0 or 1.

- The maximum value for `(t1<<2)` is 4 ('b100).
- The maximum value for `((t2 ^ t1 ^ t3)<<1)` is 2 ('b10).
- The maximum value for `t3` is 1 ('b1).

So, the maximum sum of those 3 terms is 7.